# Multiple Drop-downs showing all values

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a product that needs to have two drop-downs. I have it set up like this in admin:

[image]

However when it renders on the page, both of the drop-downs have the values from each other. Is this normal behaviour? I can't find anyone else experiencing this same issue. If I change one of them to checkboxes then the values are correct. It only seems to be happening when there are multiple drop-downs.

[image]

Comment: this is not normal behaviour , are you using any extension or custom code to display custom options in frontend?

Comment: I've tried disabling all extensions, and i'm using the base version of select.phtml. No changes.

Comment: I've also downloaded a clean version of app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php

Comment: which version you are using of Magento 1? I checked in Magento 1.9.3.4 and it is working fine

Comment: Version 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Found it! In my product > view.phtml I had the following:

```
var my_options = $j(".product-custom-option option");
var selected = $j(".product-custom-option").val();

my_options.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (a.text > b.text) return 1;
    if (a.text < b.text) return -1;
    return 0
})

$j(".product-custom-option").empty().append( my_options );
$j(".product-custom-option").val(selected);
```

I amended this to be able to handle multiples as follows:

```
$j(".product-custom-option").each(function(){
     var my_options = $j(this).find('option');
     var selected = $j(this).val();

     my_options.sort(function(a,b) {
         if (a.text > b.text) return 1;
         if (a.text < b.text) return -1;
         return 0
     });

     $j(this).empty().append( my_options );
     $j(this).val(selected);
 });
```